# Changing background of button depending on current background

Tags: java, android, button, background-color

I'm trying to change the background of a button when it's clicked but also be able to change it back when it's clicked again. What I'm trying to do is get the buttons current background and if it is (xxxxx) then change it to (yyyyy). I can't seem to find how to get the button's current background and compare it to one of my drawable resources.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Some pseudo code of what I'm trying to do:

```
if (button1.getBackground() == R.drawable.someDrawable) {
   button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.someOtherDrawable);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the right way: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: Thanks Pedro, is the "package" the package that I declared when created my project? Here's what it said in the link you posted...
    In XML: @[package:]drawable/filename

Comment: This my own simple selector:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/dxb" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/dxa" />      <!-- default -->
 </selector>

Answer (score 1):

I simple solution will be to have two drawables for background. One for non_pressed_selector and pressed_selector and just keep track if the button is pressed or not.

```
private boolean isPressed = false;
public void onClick() {
    if (isPressed) {
        // set not_pressed_selector
    } else {
        // set pressed_selector
    }
    isPressed != isPressed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a `ToggleButton` instead of simple `Button`. You could use `isChecked()` method to determine the state of your button in `OnClickListener` and set your background there. Or you can define selector in xml as pedr0 said.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was:

Declare the button in it's initial state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/StateA"/>
</selector>
```

Then I manage the events from the code controling the actual state of the button with a tag:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawables_buttons);  //This is the layout where it's the button

    threeStateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.three_States_Button);  //This is the button
    threeStateButton.setOnTouchListener(new CustomTouchListener());    
    threeStateButton.setTag("StateA");    //Set the control tag
}

private class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  //When you lift your finger
                if (threeStateButton.getTag().equals("StateA"))
                {
                    threeStateButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.StateB);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "This gonna change my state from StateA to StateB",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    threeStateButton.setTag("StateB");
                }
                else  //If when you lift your finger it was already on stateB
                {
                    threeStateButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_button);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "This gonna change my state from StateB to StateA",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    threeStateButton.setTag("StateA");
                }
                break;
            //In case you want that you button shows a different state when your finger is pressing it.
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                threeStateButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.StateButtonPressed);
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it works, and yes, I'd like to know wich is the optimal way.